# Identifiableobject Xml Missing Node Info in Web 8.5 While It Exists in 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013-sp1, web8.5, tom.net, tbb

We are upgrading to Web 8.5 from 2013 SP1 and noticed the TOM.NET API on the C# TBBs by default behave differently on Web 8.5 as opposed to 2013 SP1.

We have a C# TBB like this:

```
IdentifiableObject identifiableObject = engine.GetObject("tcm:x-x-x");
System.Xml.XmlElement xmlElement = identifiableObject.ToXml();
```

In 2013 SP1 the **xmlElement** for a Publication looks like this:

```
<tcm:Publication xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ID="tcm:0-12-1" IsEditable="false">
    <tcm:Info>
      <tcm:LocationInfo>
        <tcm:WebDAVURL>/webdav/040%20Web%20Site</tcm:WebDAVURL>
        <tcm:Path>\</tcm:Path>
      </tcm:LocationInfo>
      <tcm:VersionInfo>
        <tcm:CreationDate>2014-04-24T09:43:29</tcm:CreationDate>
        <tcm:RevisionDate>2018-09-10T14:09:26</tcm:RevisionDate>
        <tcm:Creator xlink:type="simple" xlink:title="DOMAIN\12345" xlink:href="tcm:0-59-65552" />
      </tcm:VersionInfo>
      <tcm:AllowedActions>
        <tcm:Actions Allow="9216" Deny="3689344" Managed="0" />
      </tcm:AllowedActions>
    ...
</tcm:Publication>
```

In Web 8.5, however, the **LocationInfo** and the **VersionInfo** nodes are missing.

```
<tcm:Publication xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ID="tcm:0-12-1" IsEditable="">
  <tcm:Info>
    <tcm:AllowedActions>
      <tcm:Actions Allow="25600" Deny="3672960" Managed="0" AllowedActions="tcm:Search,tcm:View,tcm:Delete" DeniedActions="tcm:Publish,tcm:UnPublish,tcm:Edit,tcm:RePublish,tcm:BlueprintManaged,tcm:PermissionManaged,tcm:WorkflowManaged" />
    </tcm:AllowedActions>
  </tcm:Info>
  <tcm:Data>
    <tcm:Title>040 Web Site</tcm:Title>
  </tcm:Data>
</tcm:Publication>
```

I presume the default behavior in Web 8.5 doesn't load all the info and I'd have to explicitly load them. My questions are:

1) How do I get the XML to return the **LocationInfo** and **VersionInfo**?

2) Why is the default behavior in Web 8.5 different from 2013 SP1?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue on my Web 8.5 server. I have tested following code: IdentifiableObject identifiableObject = engine.GetObject("tcm:0-XXX-1");
System.Xml.XmlElement xmlElement = identifiableObject.ToXml();
log.Debug(xmlElement.OuterXml); on both Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 and Web 8.5 and both results have LocationInfo and VersionInfo in xml.

Comment: I'm not sure, Maybe permission Web 8.5 different from 2013 SP1 accessing the core service

Comment: @StefanKlasnic Sorry, my question wasn't clear. I'm passing a Publication object to an IdentifiableObject and the XML was for the Publication object. So I have something like this: Publication publication = GetPublication(); and this publication is passed to another function that takes in an  IdentifiableObject - GetWebDavUrl(IdentifiableObject idObject) { XmlElment xmlElement = idObject.ToXml();  log.Debug(xmlElement.xmlElement)} }

Comment: @SabarishSenthilnathan maybe publication is not fully loaded in GetPublication() method. You can try to reload it in GetWebDavUrl() method with Load(LoadFlags flags) or Reload() methods. Also if you want to get WebDavUrl of your publication there is no need for GetWebDavUrl() method. Publication has WebDavUrl property that you can use.

Comment: Thanks @StefanKlasnic! You are right, we could use the Publcation's WebDavUrl property. We were just curious as to why not all properties aren't loaded in Web 8.5 when in 2013 sp1 it is loaded. This is just one example. We have several instances where we parse an XML to get the required properties for a better performance and if not all properties are loaded we'd have to refactor the code in several places.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently when you pass a **Publication** object to a function that takes in an **IdentifiableObject** `GetXXX(IdentifiableObject identifiableObject)`, the identifiableObject's XML will have less information to reduce the load in Web 8.5 and I had to explicitly load the state of the object using load flags as this would impact the result of the `ToXml()` method. So before getting the XML, I had to do:

```
identifiableObject.Load(LoadFlags.Expanded);
```

This wasn't necessary for 2013 SP1.